# Still pay for a cancelled transaction with a credit card?

Tags: credit-card

A credit card in U.S. has a monthly billing cycle.

If one makes a transaction with his credit card, and then cancel it and the refund can take some time (e.g. two weeks or more) to complete, does he still need to pay the credit card for the transaction , if the refund completes in the next billing cycle? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the refund is received prior to the due date of your credit card, it will be counted as a payment. However, you may owe interest for the balance during that time frame.

Since you don't know exactly when the credit will be performed, I'd recommend against counting on it. Pay the balance shown on your statement and let the credit go towards your next month's spending.

Comment: I agree, but I have also tried _calling_ the credit-card company to tell them that a refund was coming, and in _many_ cases (not all cases), they put a hold on the amount so I did not have to pay that month's bill in full. When the credit came, the hold was removed and everything was fine.